# Data structure that contains a list of arrays of strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I do not know which data structure should I use to implement something like this:

`data = {"name", "surname", "age", //listOfFriend {"Jon", "Sansa", "Arya", "Ramsay"}}`

I was thinking about this: `public ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> listaInterventi = new ArrayList<>();`
but I'm not sure.
Can you help me?

Comment: Having multiple lists nested inside another gets confusing really quickly. It would be more readable to have a ArrayList of a Class. Even for simple case like this one.

Comment: You should write a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a class, Person, with name, surname, and age fields as well as an ArrayList field for friends.

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;

    List<String> friends;

    public Person(String name, String surname, int age, List<String> friends) {
      this.name = name;
      this.surname = surname;
      this.age = age;
      this.friends = friends;
    }    
}

List<String> friends = new Arraylist<String>();
friends.add("Chicken");
friends.add("Weedwacker");
friends.add("CornCob");
Person person = new Person("Name", "Surname", 42, friends);
```

Comment: thanks, and how can I add strings in friends inside the constructor?

Comment: I expanded the answer. I would definitely suggest taking a look at some Java tutorials to better understand what's happening here.